# Use trace data as metric in Application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights

Is it possible to mark data from a trace as being a metric?

E.g. if i have a trace with a JSON message, would I be able to mark a field in the JSON document as a metric.

Does it even make sense doing so, or are there better alternatives? I just want to be able to track/graph and receive alerts on the field in the JSON document.

Comment: And how are your traces created, do you do this using the SDK? What language is your app in?

Comment: I'm trying adding Application Insights to an existing app, I have it hooked up as a target for NLog. Thats why i would like to be able to "parse" the existing traces, rather that having define and send new metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing i can think of would be to parse out the metric part of your json document, and actually send it as a metric in your trace call?

```
string theMessage = whatever;
// .. code to parse apart the message, find the json, and grab metric values
// and put them into a dictionary<string,double>
// and any other string values into a dictionary<string,string>
telemetryClient.TrackTrace( theMessage,    
    optionalDictionaryOfStringToStringProperties,    
    optionalDictionaryOfStringToDoubleMetricValues );
```

there's no "automatic" way to do what you want, having the backend parse out values from a trace that contains json.

However, you could parse those values back out in a query if you're using the analytics portal.  the query language there lets you do string manipulations, parsing, json parsing, etc.  so if you just need it downstream for some kind of analysis, you don't need to do any of that, just do it in the query.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to avoid having to add additional code. I have hooked NLog up to Application Insights on an existing app. The Analytics Portal sounds like the answer for now, even though i can't create alarms on that.